# GRS test does not reject a scalar multiple of the market factor

Tags: time-series, asset-pricing, capm

I have been playing with the GRS test (see my R script below) in relation to [Why not use a time series regression when the factor is not a return?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75806). I generated a $10,000\times 26$ matrix of returns on 25 "portfolios" and the market portfolio according to the CAPM. I used the function `GRS.test::GRS.test` in R to test the CAPM, and I could not reject the $H_0$. Then I added idiosyncratic $\alpha$s to each "portfolio", tested the CAPM again and now could easily reject the $H_0$. So far so good.

Then I generated data according to the CAPM again and ran the GRS test with the market's excess return replaced by an unrelated random variable (a random factor). The test easily rejected $H_0$.
For completeness, I added idiosyncratic $\alpha$s to each "portfolio" and tested the CAPM again with the random factor. As in the case with the true factor, I could again easily reject the $H_0$. So far so good.

Then I generated data according to the CAPM again and ran the GRS test with the market's excess return replaced by a scalar multiple of itself with a scaling factor $c=100$. To my surprise, the test could not reject the $H_0$! The $p$-value distribution over the simulation runs was close to Uniform[0,1], as we would expect when testing the true factor.
For completeness, I added idiosyncratic $\alpha$s to each "portfolio" and tested the CAPM again with the random factor. As in the case with the true factor, I could again easily reject the $H_0$.

**Question:** What is going on? Should the GRS test not reject a model with a scalar multiple of the true factor?

*(You can **run the script online** and see the results for yourself at https://rdrr.io/snippets/. Just paste the script there and click "Run". You may deleted the # symbol before the commented lines to vary between the specifications of $\alpha$s and the factor that is supplied to the GRS test.)*

```r
library(MASS)
library(GRS.test)
data("data")  # Fama-French data: market's excess return and 25 portfolios (5x5, sorted on SMB and HML) 
data=data/100 # because original data was in percent

M=1e2 # number of simulation runs
T=1e4 # sample size (length of time series)
N=25  # number of test assets/portfolios
#c=1   # scaling factor
c=100 # scaling factor

Sigma=cov(data[,c(8:32,2)])    # empirical covariance matrix; the last column is the market, the other 25 columns are the portfolios
alpha =rep(0,N+1)              # Jensen's alpha is set to zero for all assets
#set.seed(-1); alpha=runif(n=N+1,min=-0.01,max=0.01) # Jensen's alpha, in this case nonzero for all assets
beta_m=rep(NA,N+1); for(i in 1:(N+1)) beta_m[i]=Sigma[i,N+1]/Sigma[N+1,N+1] # actual betas from Fama-French data
mu_mte=rep(mean(data[,2]),T)   # expected value of market excess return, in this case time-constant and in line with Fama-French data

results=list(); pvals=rep(NA,M)
for(j in 1:M){
 # Generate a matrix of returns according to a 1 factor model with a scaling constant c for the factor:
 set.seed(j); r_matrix=mvrnorm(n=T, mu=alpha+beta_m*mean(mu_mte), Sigma=Sigma)
 f_matrix=cbind(r_matrix[,N+1])*c               # factor return matrix for the function GRS.test()
 #set.seed(-j); f_matrix=cbind(rnorm(T,mean=5)) # random, unrelated factor returns
 results[[j]]=GRS.test(r_matrix[,1:N],f_matrix) # GRS test
 pvals[j]=results[[j]]$GRS.pval
}

# Plot p-values of all simulation runs of the GRS test
plot(sort(pvals),xlim=c(0,M),ylim=c(0,1)); abline(a=0,b=1/M,lwd=2,col="red")
```

P.S. At first, there was also a puzzle about not being able to reject a random factor, but that was solved by increasing the sample size and thereby the power of the test. The related question and answer can be found [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/75966).

Comment: If $\mathbb{E}[R_{it}^e]=\beta_i\mathbb{E}[R_{mt}^e]$ then also $\mathbb{E}[R_{it}^e]=\frac{\beta_i}{c}\times c \times \mathbb{E}[R_{mt}^e]$

Comment: So in this particular case the zero alpha property is preserved even though the factor is not a return.

Comment: @fes, right... Or I could say, the factor is a return on $10\times$ the market portfolio (some kind of a leveraged position?). In that case, my simulation shows that while tests based on time series regressions cannot be used for factors that are not returns, they are sometimes fruitless even when the factor is a return.

Comment: Ok yeah actually you can think that as a return. I guess it comes back to Roll: a multiple of the market portfolio excess return is essentially the excess return on a portfolio of the equity only market portfolio and the risk-free asset, which is mean-variance efficient if the market portfolio is, so the alpha should be zero.

Comment: "In that case, my simulation shows that while tests based on time series regressions cannot be used for factors that are not returns, they are sometimes fruitless even when the factor is a return" Not sure I understand this part.

Comment: @fes, I mean my simulation only shows the latter part, not the former one. The former is taken from Cochrane's textbook. So Cochrane says we should not use [tests based on] time series regressions when the factor is not a return. My simulation shows that tests based on time series regressions may fail even when the factor is a return. So we have a problem when the factor is not a return (except when its risk premium is its mean), but the factor being a return does not *necessarily* prevent the problem either.

Comment: To me it seems that you are basically testing the CAPM in rewritten form and found that it cannot be rejected. I do not necessarily see a problem here.